# Setting up credentials using AWS.config.update in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I've tried to set up access key, secret key and region as below.(an .env file is set up and located in root directory with these keys information)

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
require('dotenv').config();

AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
});

const userRegister = ses.sendEmail(params).promise();
```

However, as I tested this, I always got this error

```
ses email on register InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

My IAM user has full Admin permission. If i add directly keys value, it works perfectly.

```
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: 'ABCDEF',
  secretAccessKey: 'CDFJ22332',
  region: 'us-east-1',
});
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you tried to `console.log(process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID)` ?

Comment: Yes, to make sure that dotenv worked, I put that line right at the top (3rd line) and saw the value of KEY ID on console. But somehow, AWS.config.update could not retrieve it.

Comment: out of curiosity, did you change your name after reputation reaching 1,111 ?

Comment: Whatever you are doing suppose to work, another similar approach is Loading from JSON file directly to AWS - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-json-file.html

Comment: I think I did change my name ;) and thanks for the AWS link.

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

Comment: Why would the OP need to remove it?